# Are OEM batteries the best way to go?

Tags: laptop, battery

I have a two year old of which the battery just died - the laptop will only work if plugged in. Are non-OEM batteries just as good as OEM batteries?

Comment: I'd suggest not closing this question, it's about the quality of batteries, not which brand to actually buy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's really no answer to your question. It's not about whether or not the battery is OEM, it's about the battery quality itself.

While it's impossible to check if the battery is good before you buy it (especially if online), you can definitely opt for new batteries (as opposed to used), and batteries that come with a warranty (just in case you need to return/exchange it).

You should also check the reputation of the battery maker (say, Dell), and of the seller (New Egg, for example). You can use the internet to search for reviews on products, manufacturers, and online stores. And for the USA and Canada, you can use the [Better Business Bureau](http://www.bbb.org/) businesses up to find out how reputable they are.

So when looking for a new battery ask yourself:

- Is the battery new?
- Does it come with a good warranty?
- What do the reviews say?
- Can I trust this place not to steal my money, or sell me junk?

Answer (score 2):

Please see this review of OEM batteries:

http://reviews.ebay.com/OEM-batteries-Why-bother_W0QQugidZ10000000001503904

EDIT: Removed editorial.

Comment: I think you're confusing what OEM means. OEM is Original Equipment Manufacturer. An OEM battery would be supplied/authorized by the company that made the notebook, come with a warranty, and not be a 'white-box' or 'aftermarket' battery. OEM batteries have to meet the notebook manufacturer's specs and quality controls. Like the guy says in the article you linked "Problem with many off brands is that they are not subject to the same quality control as OEM parts".

Comment: @techie: Thanks, I removed my comment as it had several inaccuracies, leaving the link.

Answer (score 2):

There is no single maker of third-party batteries. Some makers are excellent, some are selling obsolete gray-market stuff that may explode.

Check for a reputable maker, who you expect to be in business in two years.  Don't buy anything that has no warranty.

Comment: Why stop with 2 years? Corsair has a friggin' awesome 10 year warranty.

Comment: I was about the "still in business" part to mean that it isn't a fly-by-night company which doesn't care about its reputation because it will take the money and run, disappear without a trace before your battery fails.  Although I have to admit that a 10 year battery warranty really is awesome.

Comment: @digitxp: Corsair makes batteries?  Have you got a link?

Comment: @jason404 Was referring to other Corsair products.

Comment: @digitxp: So what on earth has that got to do with lithium chemistry batteries, which have a limited shelf life?  Such consumables do not have long guarantees, whatever company produces them.

Comment: @digitxp:  Oh, are you really 13?  Okay, doesn't matter..

Answer (score 1):

I have purchased inexpensive batteries and had good luck with them so far, bought them off of Amazon. Last one I bought was for my Dell Latitude D600, seems to be working well, it was under $40 after shipping and tax. The vendor was MLC Distribution Inc.

I have seen this site recommended on many forums for quality replacement laptop batteries at reasonable prices.

http://www.udtek.com/laptop-battery-c-1.html

Answer (score 0):

I had success buying no-name batteries (after I discovered Dell wanted hundreds of dollars more for the same parts).

(if your interested, my [blog post about it](http://mgowen.com/2010/08/06/dell-1720-laptop-replacement-battery-and-power-adapter/) has more details)